# How to use ws-secuirty when the certificate has a password

Tags: php, certificate, wso2, ws-security, wsh

I am using wsf php from WSO2 Web Services Framework for PHP.  They have many examples of how to use a certificate, but not one that uses a certificate with a password.  How can I open a certificate with a password using this library